# Trying to check if exist a session doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to check if exist a session when the page is refreshed. If a session exist, a div with form will be hidden. Otherside, the div is shown.

After logged in, if you refresh the page for the first time, the 'login' div is hidden, but if you refresh again the 'login' div appears. How can I solve this problem? Thanks for help

**UPTADED**
HTML

```
   <div id='login'>
            <a href="#" class="closelogin"><img src="images/cancel.png" class="btn_cerrarlogin" title="Cerrar" alt="Close" /></a>
            <label name='registro' for="txtUser">Usuario</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="txtUser" id="txtUser" class="txtfield"><br>
            <label name='registro' for="txtPass">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="txtPass" id="txtPass" class="txtfield"><br>
            <span id="errors"></span>
            <input type="button" name="butConectar" id="butConectar" class="butConectar" value="Conectar">       
    </div>
    <div id="opciones">
            <a href="#" class="registroacceso" id="registro" >Reg&iacute;strate ahora!</a>
            <a href="#" class="registroacceso" id="iniciarSesion" onclick="iniciarSesion()">Iniciar sesi&oacute;n</a>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT and PHP

cabecera.php

```
 <? @header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
 session_start();
 define('MAX_IDLE_TIME', 3);
 ?>
```

index.php

```
<?
require('cabecera.php');
?>

$(document).ready(function(){

           iniciarSesion();

});

function iniciarSesion(){
         $.ajax({type: "POST",
                url: "compruebaIniciaSesion.php",
                success:function(data) {

                 if(data=='ok'){  
                    $("#login").hide();
                    $('#iniciarSesion').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="registroacceso" id="cerrarSesion" onclick="cerrarSesion()">Cerrar sesi&oacute;n</a>');
                 }
                 else{
                    $('body').append('<div id="mascara"></div>');
                    $('#mascara').fadeIn(300);
                    $("#login").delay(100).animate({
                        top: '120px',
                        podition: 'absolute'
                    }, 300).effect("bounce", { distance: 90, times: 2 }, 600).effect("bounce", { distance: 10, times: 3 }, 400);
                    var snd = new Audio("sounds/bounce.mp3");
                    snd.play(); 
                 }
                                        }
            })


}

function cerrarSesion() {

                    <?session_destroy();?>
                    $('#cerrarSesion').replaceWith('<a href="#iniciar" class="registroacceso" id="iniciarSesion" onclick="iniciarSesion()">Iniciar sesi&oacute;n</a>');   

}
```

compruebaIniciaSesion.php

```
<?php

require('cabecera.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['idUsuario'])) {
        echo 'ok';
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to study the difference between client side and server side scripting, you can't run PHP inside a Javascript function in that way

Comment: Then, Should I check if exist a session in another php using Ajax?

Comment: I have updated my code. Look please

Comment: I wouldn't recommend ajax for this, just make the check in the server and adjust the view accordingly with conditionals

Answer (score 0):

for that you need AJAX...

however, you can improve the inline php code like this:

```
<? if(....): ?>
    HTMTL or javascript code here
<? else: ?>
    HTMTL or javascript code here
<? endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled 'position' as *podition* in iniciarSesion(), try after correcting it?